# How to modify text import wizard VBA code to change column data format for a specific column?

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007

I am currently importing URLs that contain a vast amount of data. Because of this, I have to manually go through the text import wizard every time in order to format specific rows. In order to speed up this process I recorded a macro of the steps I take to import the URLs. Unfortunately, while the column headers remain the same for different URLs, their position in the database is not consistent. My goal when importing is to leave all the formats equal to "general" except the column with the header "IdNumber", which I need to import as "text". In the below code (for example), it was Array(22,2). The problem occurs when I try and import a different URL when it is the 23 or 24 column. Instead of turning IdNumber to "text" it turns a different array.

Question: Is there a way to specify certain columns with VB code to modify only a specific header column when using the text import wizard?

*Note:
If I understand correctly, the Array(X,X) function's first number is the specific column, and the second number is the format (1 for general, 2 for text, ...)

My code for the text import wizard:

```
'open the URL (urlName is a variable set as a String and is declared earlier in the code) and go through the Text Import Wizard

Workbooks.OpenText Filename:= _
    urlName _
    , Origin:=437, StartRow:=1, DataType:=xlDelimited, TextQualifier:= _
    xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=False, Semicolon:=False _
    , Comma:=True, Space:=False, Other:=False, FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, 1), _
    Array(2, 1), Array(3, 1), Array(4, 1), Array(5, 1), Array(6, 1), Array(7, 1), Array(8, 1), _
    Array(9, 1), Array(10, 1), Array(11, 1), Array(12, 1), Array(13, 1), Array(14, 1), Array(15 _
    , 1), Array(16, 1), Array(17, 1), Array(18, 1), Array(19, 1), Array(20, 1), Array(21, 1), _
    Array(22, 2), Array(23, 1), Array(24, 1), Array(25, 1), Array(26, 1), Array(27, 1), Array( _
    28, 1), Array(29, 1), Array(30, 1), Array(31, 1), Array(32, 1)), TrailingMinusNumbers _
    :=True
```

Comment: You could import the data twice - first time to find the position of the IdNumber column, then a second time using a modified `Fieldinfo` Array. You could create a function which would return that array based on the field position.

Comment: It is a massive worksheet. Is there a way to only import it once? Thanks for the thought though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Sub tester()

    Dim arr, a
    arr = GetFieldInfoArray(32, 22) 'position from first load=22...
    For Each a In arr
        Debug.Print Join(a, ",")
    Next a

    Workbooks.OpenText Filename:=urlName, Origin:=437, StartRow:=1, _
              DataType:=xlDelimited, TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, _
              ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=False, Semicolon:=False, _
              Comma:=True, Space:=False, Other:=False, _
              FieldInfo:=arr, TrailingMinusNumbers:=True


End Sub

'EDIT: adjust array lower bound from 1 to 0...
Function GetFieldInfoArray(NumFields As Integer, IdPosition As Integer)
    Dim arr(), x

    ReDim arr(0 To NumFields-1)
    For x = 1 To NumFields
        arr(x-1) = Array(x, IIf(x = IdPosition, 2, 1))
    Next x

    GetFieldInfoArray = arr
End Function
```

Comment: It imported the text find, but the IdPosition column was still improperly formatted. It was formatted general instead of text.

Comment: Did you adjust the code to add the first step (importing to find the position of the Id column?)  My code was just an example of how to do the second part of my suggested approach...

Comment: I adjusted your provided code to find the position of the column.

Comment: See my edit - I had the array bound set wrongly - just tested the edited version, and it worked for me.